# Masking file name with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have a client that has several files whose name is (for example) car.php, car_edit.php, car_review.php.  These each come with query strings - so car.php?id=1234 or car_review.php?id=321. They would like the file names to be truck*.php rather than car*.php.

I'm hoping there's a way using htaccess to convert the url string to be truck*.php and use the current car*.php files. Also if possible I'd like to forward any page asking for car*.php to truck*.php.

I've done quite a bit of searching and haven't found an answer to doing this particular thing. Does anyone know how I might do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need rewrite rules. Try something like:

```
RewriteRule ^truck(.*).php$ /car.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

Note: This is untested, so may require tweaking.

Answer (score 0):

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule  ^truck(.*)\.php$   /car$1.php  [NC]
```

ought to do it. It should automatically transfer any URL query string like id=xxx over to the car*.php rewritten URL.